# Optimizing async/await - assigning variable in forEach

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I know that using `await` in `foreach` is not a good practice due to performance, as it would await sequentially for each task.

```
foreach (var task in result)
{
     task.Stages = await GetStagesForTask(task.Id);
}
```

So how can I improve that code? I was trying to do something like this:

```
List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var task in result)
{
    var stage = GetStagesForTask(task.Id);
    listOfTasks.Add(stage);
    task.Stages = stage;
}

await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
```

but of course because of incorrect type here `task.Stages = stage;` it won't work.

Comment: In this line: `foreach (var task in result)`, what is the type of the `task` variable?

Comment: How do you know that using `await` in `foreach` is not a good practice? AFAIK it's a perfectly valid approach. It is simple, it doesn't introduce concurrency/thread-safety considerations, and in many cases (for example accessing databases/filesystems) it has comparable performance with a concurrent approach.

Comment: Why you say that "I know that using await in foreach is not a good practice due to performance"? Where does that come from? The two aproaches are best suit depending on the case, example: using Task.WaitAll is good if you making multilpe Http requests, rowever, if you are performing any kind of db operation inside the Task, is not recommended if you not use any "lock" and that is the same as using await inside the loop baically, many dbs dont support multiple cons updating the same rows, or file being ued by more than one thread, and that can be a BIG problem. Not to mention mem consuption

Comment: Good point @MestreDosMagros but for example if each query is idenpendent then awaiting for every single result is a waste of resources. So tl;dr if operations are independent it's better to do them concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ with an asynchronous delegate:

```
var tasks = result.Select(async task =>
{
    var stage = await GetStagesForTask(task.Id);
    task.Stages = stage;
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or introduce a local function:

```
List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();

async Task SetStagesAsync(YourTask task)
{
    task.Stages = await GetStagesForTask(task.Id);
}

foreach (var task in result)
{
    listOfTasks.Add(SetStagesAsync(task));
}

await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
```

Or even a combination of the two:

```
async Task SetStagesAsync(YourTask task)
{
    task.Stages = await GetStagesForTask(task.Id);
}

await Task.WhenAll(result.Select(SetStagesAsync));
```

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit why this is not workng the same as `foreach` even though `await` is in Select loop?

Comment: Assuming `GetStagesForTask` is truly asynchronous (i.e. releases the thread), the `async` lambda will return an incomplete `Task`. This allows subsequent iterations to take place without waiting for the previous to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Johnathan Barclay's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68164727/11178549) is perfect if you don't mind mutating concurrently the `Stages` property of your entities. But if you prefer to defer the mutations until all the asynchronous operations have been completed, then you could consider projecting your entities to a list of `Task<Action>`s, then `await`ing these tasks using the `Task.WhenAll`, and finally invoking sequentially all the resulting [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action)s:

```
Task<Action>[] tasks = entities.Select(async entity =>
{
    var stages = await GetStagesForEntityAsync(entity.Id);
    return new Action(() => entity.Stages = stages);
}).ToArray();

Action[] actions = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var action in actions) action.Invoke();
```

In the above example I have renamed the `task` and `result` variables of your example to `entity`/`entities`, to prevent any confusion between your entities and the built-in [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) class.

The LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) operator makes it easy to project one enumerable to another, and it's especially handy when you want to create a list of custom tasks from a list of objects.

Answer (score -1):

A neat way to solve this issue is to create a thread for each task, the `await` would happen inside the separate threads. So, you would create the threads in a `foreach`, they would do the await in separate threads and then another `foreach` would call `.Join()` for each thread. In this manner you will not have sequential await, but create the threads, they would work in parallel and you will wait as much as your longest task and not as much as the sum of the time needed for all tasks.

However, if you have many tasks, then beware eating up all resources. If you have many tasks, then break them into chunks of maybe 10 threads and apply the approach I have described above.

Comment: Can't this be achived use `Parallel.ForEach()` ?

Comment: @StefanoCavion yes, it can be achieved by those means, you are correct.

Comment: @StefanoCavion Parallel never should be used with async/await. It is a popular bug introduced during migration to async flow. Async delegates return Task and the Parallel construct doesn't await that task. Exceptions are unobserved and you can't be sure after the Parallel.For invocations has run that all the work has actually been completed.

Comment: Just look on the Parallel implementation:
`public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body);` so there is `Action<T>` instead `Func<Task<T>>`

Comment: @DiPix thanks for the clarification. I still doesn't find  why I should do something like a `foreach` with an `await` inside instead of doing a `Task.Run` and `await` the result of it can you give me a hint?